# parsing csv file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I'm trying to write a node.js server. 
the server should save the request variables in a local csv file which will be constantly updated:

Get mt/server/?var1=0&var2=foo

should result in:

var1,var2

0,'foo'

then another request should change the file:

Get mt/server/?var1=1&var3=bar

var1,var2,var3

0,'foo'

1,,'bar'

until now i'm only able to overwrite the file.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var csv = require( "fast-csv" );

var FILENAME = "data.csv";

function onRequest(request, response) {
    if (request.method == 'GET' && request.url[1]=='?') {

        console.log("a user made a request at url:  " + request.url);

        response.writeHead(200, {"Context-type":"text/plain"});
        response.write("something to write");

        var queryObject = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
        console.log(queryObject);

        fast_csv_write(FILENAME,queryObject);
        fast_csv_read(FILENAME);

        response.end();
    }
}

function fast_csv_read(filename)
{
    csv.fromPath(filename)
    .on("data", function(data){
        console.log("current data: ");
        console.log(data);
})
.on("end", function(){
    console.log("done reading");
});

}
function fast_csv_write(filename,queries)
{
    var csvStream = csv.format({headers: true}),
    writableStream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

    writableStream.on("finish", function(){
    console.log("done writing.");
    });

    csvStream.pipe(writableStream);
    csvStream.write(queries);
    csvStream.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3001);
console.log("server running .... ");
```

I've read through fast-csv README : https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv

but that didn't give me enough information.

can anyone explain how can i accomplish this or give a better documentation that might help me?

Comment: try to create a csv manually...don't go for an existing library

Comment: Try this library, much better than fast-csv and more mature too:  https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv